# Login to JIRA using C#

Tags: c#, curl, jira

We have limited user license in our JIRA instance that is much smaller than the number of employees in the company. But we'd like to have all employees the ability to view our JIRA dashboard (i.e view projects, view issues, etc). I've read some workaround that we can create one read-only access account in JIRA, then create another login form that would authenticate the employees. Once the employee supplied the correct credentials to be authenticated, the program will then submit the secret read-only account to Atlassian.

I can connect to CURL (status: 200), but I would like something that would redirect me to our JIRA dashboard logged in with read-only account.

Here's my curl command:

```
curl -v -u "<emailaddress>:<api_token>" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --cookie "cookies.cook" --cookie-jar "cookies.cook" -d "{\"username\": \"<emailaddress>\",\"password\": \"<password>\"}" -X POST "https://<company>.atlassian.net/rest/auth/1/session"
```

Running the curl above will modify `cookies.cook` with tokens from atlassian and cloud. If I manually insert the cloud token from the cookie file to `https://id.atlassian.com/login?continue=https%3A//<company>.atlassian.net` it logs me in. (i.e Google Chrome (F12) > Console > `document.cookie=<cloudTokenName>=<cloudTokenValue>`)

Here's my C# code:

```
Uri url = new Uri("https://<company>.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa");
//Authenticate the user
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "<companydomain>"))
        {
            if (pc.ValidateCredentials(txtAdUser, txtAdPass))
            {
                var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
                cookieJar.Add(cookie);
                webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
                webRequest.Method = "POST";
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
                var authcred = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<emailaddress>:<api_token>"));
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authcred);
                webRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookieHeader);

                var data = "{\"username\":\"<emailaddress>\",\"password\":\"<password>\"}";
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data);
                webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

                Stream sw = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
                sw.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
                Response.RedirecT(ourjirainstance);
            }
        }
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Have a look at this SDK instead https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/wiki/Home

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for something illegal by definition (working around a license restriction).

Comment: @EgeÖzcan, I'm not sure why you're saying it's illegal, when I found that workaround from the Atlassian forum itself. See: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/How-to-set-up-Authenticated-Read-Only-Access/qaq-p/223033

Comment: @Miko I didn't see an official response. Anyway, you didn't describe exactly what's not working. For what it's worth, you won't be able to assign cookies for an other domain through your own domain. You may try using the api and listing the relevant issues though your own interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no C# expert, but I've been using JIRA for years, and yes, this is possible and absolutely legal, you just need to pass the appropriate headers to your next request after you received the response from curl.

According to JIRA: Their login API, `creates a new session for a user in Jira. Once a session has been successfully created it can be used to access any of Jira’s remote APIs and also the "WEB UI" by passing the appropriate HTTP Cookie header.`

Your curl request should be POST https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/auth/1/session

```
curl --request POST \
  --user email@example.com:<api_token> \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --cookie cookie.txt --cookie-jar cookie.txt
  --data '
    {
      "username": "fred",
      "password": "freds_password"
    }' \
  --url 'https://your-domain.atlassian.net/rest/auth/1/session'
```

See: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/#api-auth-1-session-post

Once you received the token, open a browser (Mozilla), go to your JIRA login page, press F12 and go to Network, edit your header by adding the token you have received from your curl and resend the request. If successful, a redirect with status 200 will appear. Go to the redirected URL (not the original URL), and you should be logged in. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking about sending the cookies from your domain to another domain; I'm afraid, I don't think it's possible. The workaround provided in the forum might be a different approach, compare to what you're trying to do. You should ask Atlassian.